# How to print the contents of a Queue

Tags: c++, queue

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to print out my entire queue (which holds weather history) and it won't work. When I try and debug it, it shows me that it is holding the values in the queue correctly, but not assigning it correctly. How can i output the contents of my queue correctly? Here is my code:

Temp.cpp

```
ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, Temperature &p)//Overloaded Method to output the data
{    
fstream myEngFile5;
string tempLine5;
string tempLine6;
myEngFile5.open("English.txt");
myEngFile5.seekg(335);
getline(myEngFile5, tempLine5);
out<<tempLine5<<p.value; //The Temperature is __
myEngFile5.seekg(356);
getline(myEngFile5, tempLine6);
out<<tempLine6<<"\n"; //F
return out;
}
```

Temp.h

```
int getTemp();
int getTemp2();

Temperature()
{
value=0;
}

Temperature(int v)
{
value=v;
}
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,Temperature &p);
```

Source.cpp

```
queue<int>temp;//decalred in the begining
.
.
.
for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){
int qSize=temp.size();
Temperature p2(temp.front());
while( !temp.empty()){
cout<<p2;
temp.pop();}
}
```

Comment: get rid of `p2` and do `cout << temp.front()`

Comment: @Dave That does solve the problem, however I need p2 because it calls my overloaded method which contains "The Temperature is:" [int from queue].

Comment: Where's the queue, or did i miss something?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My bad... the queue is temp, i edited it and changed it to make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (untested)?:

```
while (!temp.empty()) {
    Temperature p2(temp.front());
    cout << p2;
    temp.pop();
    }
```

It seems like you might be better off using queue<Temperature> and constructing your Temperature objects when you fill your queue.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. I figured it out already, but for the record you are right....I hate when little things like that throw your whole program off. Thank you!